# jQuery adds focus to every element in the page

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Open the URL in the Chrome browser

https://faq.ssa.gov/ics/support/kbanswer.asp?QuestionID=3704

launch the chrome developer tools window (by pressing F12).

select any element (for example head element). Open the Event Listeners tab. 
Notice that focus event is added by jquery.min.js

Also, focus event is added for every other node.

Can someone explain why jQuery adding this event?

Comment: I think it is so that it can fire any handlers that may be attached to the focus event for those elements.

Comment: Zack, can you explain bit more?

Comment: Never mind my first comment. I misunderstood what you were saying. I'm not sure what would cause those focus events to be added to every element in your html. Is this a personal site you created, or is it some public website that I could look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that every element in the page has the `focus` event is because they added it in the script.

You can open the [main.js](https://ssa-prod-34011.azurewebsites.net/static/js/main.js) file and go to line 168. You will find there:

```
 $('html *').focus(function () {
     hideShare(this);
 });
```

The reason they did this was to hide the share option that there is on the page when the user click/focus on any of the elements on the page.